# How to stop fieldset in form from causing a double scroll on the page?

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a form on a page in which the fieldsets create another scrollbar in the page, and makes the form scrollable. This is so weird, and its even weirder that I cant find any sort of information or solution on this anywhere. It should just continue on in the page, I have no size restriction for the form.

Here is my HTML for the form

```
<form>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Customer Information:</legend>
                    <label for="fname">First name:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
                    <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
                    <label for="email">Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email"><br><br>
                    <label for="area">Please describe your concern:</label><br>
                    <textarea name="area" id="area" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea><br><br>
                </fieldset><br>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Product Information:</legend>
                    <label for="pname">Product name:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="pname" name="pname"><br><br>
                    <label for="date">Date of Purchase:</label>
                    <input type="date" id="date" name="date"><br><br>
                    <label>Select your warranty plan:</label> <br>
                    <input type="radio" id="none" name="plan" value="none">
                    <label for="none">None</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="six" name="plan" value="six">
                    <label for="css">6 Months</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="twelve" name="plan" value="twelve">
                    <label for="javascript">12 Months</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="eighteen" name="plan" value="eighteen">
                    <label for="css">18 Months</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="twentyfour" name="plan" value="twentyfour">
                    <label for="javascript">24 Months</label><br><br>
                    <label>Select which THE BOARD SHOP locations you have shopped at: </label><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="Toronto" name="Toronto" value="Toronto">
                    <label for="Toronto"> Toronto</label><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="Montreal" name="Montreal" value="Montreal">
                    <label for="Montreal"> Montreal</label><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="California" name="California" value="California">
                    <label for="California"> California</label><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="New York" name="New York" value="New York">
                    <label for="New York"> New York</label><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="Cairo" name="Cairo" value="Cairo">
                    <label for="Cairo"> Cairo</label><br>

                </fieldset><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
            </form>
```

and the CSS

```
form {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
}

textarea {
    resize: none;
}

label,
legend,
input {
    font-family: "Kanit", sans-serif;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is this in an actual browser window or a website like jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: I tried your example and I do not get the scroll bars you describe. https://jsfiddle.net/thw0zjqb/

Comment: As Daniel mentioned above, I too copied the code to my local machine and wasn't able to reproduce a double scroll bar.